# How to move element from left to right, turn back and repeat, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a plane animation using plain JavaScript.

There is a class `Plane` with methods flyRight() and flyLeft(). In both of those class methods I am using `setInterval(fucntion() { ... }, 1)` to move the plane every 1 milisecond either to the left or to the right.

I have a problem ensuring that after executing `myPlane.flyRight()`, it doesn't execute the `myPlane.flyLeft()` - problematic lines in the snippet marked with a comment `// DOES NOT WORK`.

```js
class Plane {
  constructor(htmlId, speed) {
    this.plane = document.getElementById(htmlId);     // plane HTML element
    this.width = parseInt(document.getElementById(htmlId).offsetWidth);     // plane's width
    this.speed = speed;   // pixels per milisecond
    this.range = parseInt(window.innerWidth);     // plane's range
  }
  
  flyLeft() {
    var minLeftPos = 0 - this.width - 10;
    var planeSpeed = this.speed;
    if (this.plane.style.left === '') {
      this.plane.style.left = 0
    }
    
    var moveLeft = setInterval(function() {
      if (parseInt(this.plane.style.left) >= minLeftPos) {
        this.plane.style.left = parseInt(this.plane.style.left) - planeSpeed + 'px';
      } else {
        clearInterval(moveLeft);
        this.plane.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';    // turns around
        this.flyRight();     // DOES NOT WORK
      }
    }, 1)
  }
  
  flyRight() {
    var maxLeftPos = this.range + this.width + 10;
    var planeSpeed = this.speed;
    if (this.plane.style.left === '') {
      this.plane.style.left = 0
    }

    var moveRight = setInterval(function() {
      if (parseInt(this.plane.style.left) <= maxLeftPos) {
        this.plane.style.left = parseInt(this.plane.style.left) + planeSpeed + 'px';
      } else {
        clearInterval(moveRight);
        this.plane.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';     // turns around
        this.flyLeft();     // DOES NOT WORK
      }
    }, 1)
  }
  
  fly() {
    this.flyRight();
  }
}

myPlane = new Plane("plane", 3);
myPlane.fly();
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}


.plane {
  width: 200px;
  height: 168px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/02/10/22/airplane-303639_960_720.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="plane" class="plane"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the bindings you have within your `setInterval` functions (note at the end of the functions I use `.bind`). Callback functions used in `setInterval` and `setTimeout` need to be bound to a scope in order to handle `this`.

There is a cleaner way which would involve using arrow functions instead of `function(){}` format. The reason that method works is arrow functions preserve the [lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Lexical_scoping), which is exactly what the `bind` functions are doing. So by using arrow functions you don't have to use `.bind` at all, it comes for free.

```js
class Plane {
  constructor(htmlId, speed) {
    this.plane = document.getElementById(htmlId);     // plane HTML element
    this.width = parseInt(document.getElementById(htmlId).offsetWidth);     // plane's width
    this.speed = speed;   // pixels per milisecond
    this.range = parseInt(window.innerWidth);     // plane's range
  }
  
  flyLeft() {
    var minLeftPos = 0 - this.width - 10;
    var planeSpeed = this.speed;
    if (this.plane.style.left === '') {
      this.plane.style.left = 0
    }
    
    var moveLeft = setInterval(function() {
      if (parseInt(this.plane.style.left) >= minLeftPos) {
        this.plane.style.left = parseInt(this.plane.style.left) - planeSpeed + 'px';
      } else {
        clearInterval(moveLeft);
        this.plane.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';    // turns around
        this.flyRight();     // DOES NOT WORK
      }
    }.bind(this), 1)
  }
  
  flyRight() {
    var maxLeftPos = this.range + this.width + 10;
    var planeSpeed = this.speed;
    if (this.plane.style.left === '') {
      this.plane.style.left = 0
    }

    var moveRight = setInterval(function() {
      if (parseInt(this.plane.style.left) <= maxLeftPos) {
        this.plane.style.left = parseInt(this.plane.style.left) + planeSpeed + 'px';
      } else {
        clearInterval(moveRight);
        this.plane.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';     // turns around
        this.flyLeft();     // DOES NOT WORK
      }
    }.bind(this), 1)
  }
  
  fly() {
    this.flyRight();
  }
}

myPlane = new Plane("plane", 3);
myPlane.fly();
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}


.plane {
  width: 200px;
  height: 168px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/02/10/22/airplane-303639_960_720.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="plane" class="plane"></div>
```

Comment: Your solutin works perfectly, thanks. However I would like to ask you why is it that `this.plane` works inside those `setInterval`'s functions?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe that comes down to references. `this` is basically an object that also provides context. You were able to pass data in the form of `this.plane`, but it wasn't able to access the context, which is what it needs to access the class methods.

Comment: To get your plane to turn back around properly, the rotate should be 360deg in the `flyLeft` method.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are dealing with `JavaScript` to run this animation, but let me present you a `CSS` only solution using `animation`:

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.plane {
  transform: translate(-100%);
  animation: flyingPlane 10s linear infinite;
  width: 200px;
  height: 168px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/02/10/22/airplane-303639_960_720.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes flyingPlane {
  40% {
    transform: translate(100vw);
  } 50% {
    transform: translate(100vw) scale(-1, 1);
  } 90% {
    transform: translate(-100%) scale(-1, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I know the CSS/SASS solution, but I wanted to make a JavaScript alternative solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Change functions to arrow functions to avoid them binding there own `this`. By doing so your function within the `setInterval` will refer `this` to their parent context.

```
class Plane {
  ...
  flyLeft () {
    ...
    var moveLeft = setInterval(() => {
      ...
    }, 1)
  }

  flyRight () {
    ...

    var moveRight = setInterval(() => {
      ...
    }, 1)
  }

  ...
}
```

```js
class Plane {
  constructor(htmlId, speed) {
    this.plane = document.getElementById(htmlId);     // plane HTML element
    this.width = parseInt(document.getElementById(htmlId).offsetWidth);     // plane's width
    this.speed = speed;   // pixels per milisecond
    this.range = parseInt(window.innerWidth);     // plane's range
  }
  
  flyLeft () {
    var minLeftPos = 0 - this.width - 10;
    var planeSpeed = this.speed;
    if (this.plane.style.left === '') {
      this.plane.style.left = 0
    }
    
    var moveLeft = setInterval(() => {
      if (parseInt(this.plane.style.left) >= minLeftPos) {
        this.plane.style.left = parseInt(this.plane.style.left) - planeSpeed + 'px';
      } else {
        clearInterval(moveLeft);
        this.plane.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';    // turns around
        this.flyRight();     // DOES NOT WORK
      }
    }, 1)
  }
  
  flyRight () {
    var maxLeftPos = this.range + this.width + 10;
    var planeSpeed = this.speed;
    if (this.plane.style.left === '') {
      this.plane.style.left = 0
    }

    var moveRight = setInterval(() => {
      if (parseInt(this.plane.style.left) <= maxLeftPos) {
        this.plane.style.left = parseInt(this.plane.style.left) + planeSpeed + 'px';
      } else {
        clearInterval(moveRight);
        this.plane.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';     // turns around
        this.flyLeft();     // DOES NOT WORK
      }
    }, 1)
  }
  
  fly () {
    this.flyRight();
  }
}

myPlane = new Plane("plane", 3);
myPlane.fly();
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}


.plane {
  width: 200px;
  height: 168px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/02/10/22/airplane-303639_960_720.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="plane" class="plane"></div>
```